# Looking for large GML files containing vector polygon data

Tags: grass-gis, data, gml

I have few vector data files with 500 to 700 MB GML files. But I am looking for files larger than these preferably 1 GB, 2 GB. It would be helpful if somebody can provide some pointers regarding the place to find such files.

Note: I need to test polygon overlay over large data sets, so the two layers that I need should be intersecting.

Comment: Would you prefer a specific topic? Generally, you can get big files in any format and convert them to GML using e.g. QGIS.

Answer (score 4):

You can try some of the CanVec data, available [here](ftp://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/canada_gml/). Some of those files range from 4 MB to 50GB, depending on the one you choose.

Comment: ah CanVec... Canada's quiet beast of data! +1

Comment: +1 I was just going to say GeoBase...same thing only different

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what the data is, download the whole of the OSM data ([Planet OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)) and use [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) to get the data into PostGIS and then export to GML.

BUT.. do you really want just any old data (presumably to stress-test you network or something) or is there something particular you need?

Comment: I need to test polygon overlay over large data sets, so the two layers that I need should be intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a google search like the following and see what pops up:

gml filetype:zip

http://www.google.com/search?q=gml+filetype%3Azip